# Using memcahced in java

Tags: java, memcached

I am really new to memcache .I just tested memcached in java .The java class builds successfully but when i run the file it keeps on running never gets stopped..

The code i used is....

```
public class NewMem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException{
try {
   MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 11211));
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.err.println("connection problem");
}

}
}
```

When i run this code it give me the following and run doesn't  gets stopped..

```
init:
deps-jar:
compile-single:
run-single:
2011-11-21 12:15:58.328 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/localhost:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2011-11-21 12:15:58.328 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@1c5c1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to call the [shutdown method](http://docs.couchbase.org/membase-sdk-java-api-reference/membase-sdk-java-started.html#membase-sdk-java-started-disconnection) for the memcached client:

```
  client.shutdown();
```

Comment: Ya it works fine now thank u....how can i set mysql query result to memcache key using java .am really struggling in this.

Comment: @ash: open another question about that